# Gnuplot: How to hide data points after a a curve fit

Tags: gnuplot

This ought to be pretty simple, but I can't seem to find an answer. I have a data file that I have successfully fit a curve to. Now I would like to display the curve, but not the individual data points. How do I do that? Here's what I have now.

```
f1(x) = a1 + b1*exp(x/c1)
a1 = 1
b1 = 10
c1 = 1000
fit f1(x) 'datafile.txt' using 1:2 via a1, b1, c1
plot f1(x) , "datafile.txt"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line, you instruct gnuplot to plot both the fitted function f1(x) and the data points from the file. If you omit the filename, it will not plot the points.

Because it then no longer knows the range of the data, it will not use the same range. So you need to set the range explicitly, for example:

```
plot [0:100] f1(x)
```

Comment: Yeah, but if I don't include the file name, it displays a straight line instead of the correct curve.

Comment: That's it! I had to set the domain to the actual domain of my data set - [0,14000] in my case. Much obliged!